# How to check if MS compiler will compile my source code

Tags: c++

Guys I was trying in VS to do something like:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include "stdafx.h"
#endif
```

but I'm getting an error telling me:

```
C1020: unexpected #endif
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Edit
/*This is content of stdafx.h*/

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//

#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

//#include <stdio.h>
//#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;

// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
```

Comment: Is this the exact snippet that is causing the error? Can you show the contents of `stdafx.h`?

Comment: and what is in targetver.h ? As long as your header file is correct, the original code is correct too. Try to remove the #ifdef ... #endif in your file. Compilation should fail and give you the real error.

Comment: #PierreBdR ok, I've just found it. This code compiles but in VS in order to compile it one have to switch off precompiled headers. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot put conditionals around stdafx.h because of the way MSVC precompiled headers work. It basically replaces everything once stdafx.h has been found (and usually requires `#include "stdafx.h"` to be the first line in the file) with the precompiled header contents, so it is as if you never wrote `#if _MSC_VER` and have an extra `#endif`.

Two solutions:

1) Do not use precompiled headers in your project. You can still use stdafx.h to include all the headers you require but compilation will be slow.

2) Put the conditional compile within the stdafx.h file.

(Taken from [here](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-241276.html))

Comment: I absolutely love second option. Thanks!